# graphviz pdf generation from .dot failing with both Tpdf and Tps2

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have a `.dpt` file I am trying to output a `.png` and `.pdf` files out of it and I am using my command line expression as: `dot -Tpng SPU123.dot -o SPU123.png` to generate `.png` and it works fine. First, I tried to generate (following graphviz documentation) `.pdf` by: `dot -Tpdf SPU123.dot -o SPU123.pdf` but it just generated a blank `.pdf` and the documentation says there is something buggy with `Tpdf` option and instead use `Tps2` option so I did: `dot -Tps SPU123.dot -o SPU123.ps` but I got this error:

```
Error: canvas size (34642,3608) exceeds PDF limit (14400)
        (suggest setting a bounding box size, see dot(1))
```

How to generate `.pdf` output out of my `.dot` file?

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Did you ever find an answer?